# Angular ngClass ghost class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

I was making a simple toggle of classes with ngClass, using Material Design Icons (probably irrelevant). Here's an example:

```
<button ng-click="toggle = !toggle">
  <i class="mdi" ng-class="{'mdi-filter': toggle, 'mdi-filter-remove': !toggle}"></i>
</button>
```

And it didn't work for some reason, the 'mdi-filter-remove' class would get removed on !true evaluation. So, to test, I changed the class to 'mdi-filter-outline'. With that class it somehow works fine! I only changed the class, if I put the previous one back it stops working again. And the strangest thing is, on toggle, before switching to 'mdi-filter-outline' class the 'mdi-filter-remove' class flashes for a split second.

If I set a break-point for the toggle and start clicking 'step over next function call' I indeed see 'mdi-filter-remove' after a few clicks, right after the line 17286 in angular.js is executed:

```
fn(value, ((last === initWatchVal) ? value : last), current);
```

That class is not used ANYWHERE in the project, I searched whole project with atom, no matches! Where does it come from?

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have ngAnimate in your project? If you do, then adding and removing classes with `ng-class` causes some special classes to be added and removed behind the scenes, for use with transition animations. One of these special classes is a class with the `-remove` suffix. So for example, if you have a class called `my-class` that you are adding and removing with `ng-class`, then the classes `my-class-add` and `my-class-remove` will also show up alongside them whenever the element is transitioning. That's why you see it for a split second.

So, you should just rename your class. The `-remove` suffix is clashing with what angular is doing automatically.

Comment: You were right, it was the ngAnimate, it was adding the '*-remove' class to the ngClass element and that class corresponds to an icon class, that's why it was showing up.
But I can't change the class name, cause it's from a component, so I added
`$animate.enabled($('.filter'), false);`
where .filter is the element I do not wish to animate.
Thanks a bunch!